unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
I am using XPUT command in ElasticSearch and writing the correct command but getting same error again and again.
My code:
curl -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/movies -d '
{
        "mappings": {
                "properties": {
                        "year": {
                                "type": "date"
                        }
                }
        }
}'

And error is :
unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'


I am following course on udemy and the instructor is writing the same command and getting the work done.

Are you sure this problem is related to cURL? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

I have tried many alternatives suggested by my manager and other ways to resolve this, but not able to solve the issue. I am stuck at the putting the data into the elastic search.

Try like this:
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "year": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}'

Note: Use https and -k flag in the curl request if Elasticsearch http layer security is enabled.
If you have kibana you can run like the following:
PUT movies
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "year": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}


I have tried this, but got same error.

This error typically occurs when there's a missing closing quotation mark in a string. I check it, test it and it's working fine. In which environment did you run this command? If it's linux can you try to put this into a shell script and run it like sh create_index.sh

I have tried using shell script and ran .sh file, but giving same error only.

I strongly believe that there is a typo issue or something like that, please try to copy/paste directly from my answer or type manually with pressing the tab button.
Also, try postman. https://www.postman.com/

Thanks alot brother, it worked in postman. But, I will try and find out the problem while using this curl command in PuTTY.

You're welcome brother. Happy to hear at least the postman worked :).

Hey, I have asked the instructor of the course regarding the problem I am facing using curl then he replied "This error suggest an issue with the curl version that we created at minute 3:00 of the course, please review for any typos in this steps edit/save using nano editor then retry the put command."

But I have done the same steps as the instructor did, and then also I am facing the problem. Although it is working fine on Postman ,  but I want to do handson with curl on Putty. Please help me if possible.

Hello again @DilpreetSingh, as you can see the command is working. So the problem can be because of your linux curl command. try to update it, or create a docker container that's curl in it and try with that.

Just tried with mobaxterm and it is working fine. Maybe some issues with Putty.
Thanks

Happy to hear that's working again :) Accept that as an answer if it helped.
